# Order data set using pandas dataframe based on lowest value inside

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataset that I would like to order by date but second order with 'pass' value lowest inside of highest. The reason I don't have any code is because, I just have no idea where to begin.

dataframe input:

```
index   date    pass
0   11/14/2014  1
1   3/13/2015   1
2   3/20/2015   1
3   5/1/2015    2
4   5/1/2015    1
5   5/22/2015   3
6   5/22/2015   1
7   5/22/2015   2
8   9/25/2015   1
9   9/25/2015   2
10  9/25/2015   3
11  12/4/2015   2
12  12/4/2015   1
13  2/12/2016   2
14  2/12/2016   1
15  5/27/2016   1
16  6/10/2016   1
17  9/23/2016   1
18  12/23/2016  1
19  11/24/2017  1
20  12/29/2017  1
21  1/26/2018   2
22  1/26/2018   1
23  2/9/2018    1
24  3/16/2018   1
25  4/6/2018    2
26  4/6/2018    1
27  6/15/2018   1
28  6/15/2018   2
29  10/26/2018  1
30  11/30/2018  1
31  12/21/2018  1
```

```
** Expected Output **
index   date    pass
0   11/14/2014  1
1   3/13/2015   1
2   3/20/2015   1
3   5/1/2015    2
4   5/1/2015    1

5   5/22/2015   3
6   5/22/2015   2
7   5/22/2015   1

8   9/25/2015   3
9   9/25/2015   2
10  9/25/2015   1
11  12/4/2015   2
12  12/4/2015   1
13  2/12/2016   2
14  2/12/2016   1
15  5/27/2016   1
16  6/10/2016   1
17  9/23/2016   1
18  12/23/2016  1
19  11/24/2017  1
20  12/29/2017  1

21  1/26/2018   1
22  1/26/2018   2

23  2/9/2018    1
24  3/16/2018   1

25  4/6/2018    1
26  4/6/2018    2

27  6/15/2018   1
28  6/15/2018   2
29  10/26/2018  1
30  11/30/2018  1
31  12/21/2018  1
```

I have spaced out the results that would change. index 5,6,7 and 21,21 and 25,26.  So all the bigger pass numbers should be inside the lower pass number if the dates are same.

So if you look at INDEX 5,6,7 the pass for it is changed to 3,2,1 and if you look at INDEX 25,26 the pass is changed to 1,2. Hope you understand.

Comment: what is the lowest inside highest ...

Comment: @WeNYoBen so the lowest pass number should be indexed within higher pass number ONLY if dates are same

Comment: Can you post expected output?

Comment: This is confusing... some pass are sorted large to small and others small to large for the same date.

Comment: Scott.. yes.. that is the hard part.. basically the higher pass should be the outer layer of inner pass.

Comment: I don't understand the concept of layering.

Comment: so if the dates are the same.. than lower pass should always be indexed inside of higher pass.. so I would always want output as 3,2,1,1,2,3 for example but dates still ordered by dates.

Comment: So if you look at INDEX 5,6,7 the pass for it is changed to 3,2,1 and if you look at INDEX 25,26 the pass is changed to 1,2.  Hope you understand

Comment: So on 5/22 why aren't those three pass 1,2,3 instead of 3,2,1?

Comment: @ScottBoston Because that is the way I would like it.. forinstance.. 3,2,1,1,2,3.  like imagine it having circle with int a circle..idk how to explain better than than.

Comment: But then for dates 4/6 where the order s already 2,1, you want to switch it to 1,2?  2,1,1,2 doesn't apply? It seems arbitrary with a single date.  I am curious to if the logic should go beyond a single date.

Comment: 5/1/15 stays 2,1 but 1/25, 4/6 and 6/15 switch to 1,2?

Comment: @ScottBoston yes, Order is 2,1 but it should be 1,2.  And yes.. u'r last comment was on point about  -->> 5/1/15 stays 2,1 but 1/25, 4/6 and 6/15 switch to 1,2?

Comment: Why does 5/1 stay 2,1 and the other dates change to 1,2?

Comment: @ScottBoston so lets say you have [ { ( ... ) } ], so lets say they these brackets has dates as their key and they were same date.. but they should be shorted in closing order.. Hope you understand.

Comment: Sorry.  But no.  This doesn't explain why 5/1 is 2,1 and other dates are 1,2.

Answer (score 0):

Order first by pass then do it by date. This way you will be sure to have your df the way you want it

Comment: that would only work for either top or bottom because it will either put decreasing pass or increasing pass.. and not both